# Plugin doesn't support this project's cordova-android version. cordova-android: 6.2.3, failed version requirement: >=6.3.0 in oracle MAF2.5

Tags: cordova, oracle-maf

i am using jdeveloper 12.2.1.3 with MAF extension 2.5

I need help to find out Cordova Plugins that is compatible with oracle maf 2.5

whenever i try to use any cordova  plugin  like

1- cordova-plugin-file-transfer

2- cordova-plugin-media-capture

i got the following error

**[09:02:17 AM] Plugin doesn't support this project's cordova-android version. cordova-android: 6.2.3, failed version requirement: >=6.3.0**

[09:02:17 AM] Skipping 'cordova-plugin-media-capture' for android

what does this error means ??

how and where i can find out the cordova plugins that is compatible with oracle MAF 2.5

Thanks in advance

Kashif Ali

Answer (score 0):

As plugins evolve, they require newer **Cordova** and **platform** versions. In this case, your cordova-android version is [6.2.3](https://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2017/05/04/android-release.html), which is almost a year old now. In terms of Cordova apps, a year means it's now practically obsolete.

You'll have to somehow **upgrade your cordova-android version**.

Unfortunately I can't help you on how exactly to do it with **JDeveloper**, because I only use **Visual Studio** now which is very powerful to manage Cordova and its platforms. You may also try **NetBeans** but it is more complicated. Or you could also manually create and manage the Cordova app using the **command line interface** (not complex, but requires patience and lots of command line typing).

This last method, the **CLI**, has the huge advantage that whenever you download a platform or a plugin, you ensure to get the latest stable version directly from the Apache Cordova servers.

To create a new app using the CLI, (if you have already installed [NodeJS](https://nodejs.org/en/)) run this:

```
cordova create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld
```

Then to add the latest cordova-android platform, type this:

```
cordova platform add android
```

Now, your new app will be using latest Cordova 8.0 and [cordova-android 7.1.0](https://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2018/02/26/cordova-android-7.1.0.html) and you should be able to install your plugins.